# The hadoop-yarn cgroup directory is deleted after each "systemctl daemon-reload" command

Tags: hadoop-yarn, cgroups

I have an Hadoop cluster and I need to activate cgroups in order to use GPU in docker environment.
My hadoop version is 3.3.4 so I followed : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManagerCgroups.html

As it's written in the documentation, I kept the parameter yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.mount to false in order manage the cgroup myself (security reason).

As I'm on CentOS 8, I use cgroup v1.
I defined the parameters :
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.hierarchy to /hadoop-yarn
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.mount-path to /sys/fs/cgroup

Yarn needs 3 cgroups : cpu, cpuacct and devices.

In order to have the /haddop-yarn persistent, I've install libcgroup rpm
then I've updated /etc/cgconfig.conf with

```
group hadoop-yarn {
        perm {
                admin {
                        uid = yarn;
                        gid = hadoop;
                }
                task {
                        uid = yarn;
                        gid = hadoop;
                }
        }
        cpu {
        }
        cpuacct {
        }
        devices {
        }
}
```

and I've started cgconfig service. The 3 directories are created :

```
$ ll /sys/fs/cgroup/{cpu,cpuacct,devices}/hadoop-yarn/ -d
drwxr-xr-x 2 yarn hadoop 0 Sep  8 13:15 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/hadoop-yarn/
drwxr-xr-x 2 yarn hadoop 0 Sep  8 13:15 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/hadoop-yarn/
drwxr-xr-x 2 yarn hadoop 0 Sep  8 13:27 /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/hadoop-yarn/
```

At this point, I can restart the Yarn NodeManager.

However, each time that someone execute `systemctl daemon-reload`, the devices directory is deleted :

```
$ ll /sys/fs/cgroup/{cpu,cpuacct,devices}/hadoop-yarn/ -d
ls: cannot access '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/hadoop-yarn/': No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x 2 yarn hadoop 0 Sep  8 13:15 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/hadoop-yarn/
drwxr-xr-x 2 yarn hadoop 0 Sep  8 13:15 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/hadoop-yarn/
```

I see nothing in logs, I have no idea why this directory is deleted.
And of course, Yarn NodeManager needs this directory, so the NodeManager doesn't work anymore and needs to be restarted (once the directory has been re-created of course).

As an other solution of cgconfig service, I've tested to create my own service that will create these directories.

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/hadoop-yarn-cgroup.service

[Unit]
Description=Custom cgroup for Hadoop YARN

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/hadoop-yarn
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/hadoop-yarn
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/hadoop-yarn
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown -R yarn:hadoop /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/hadoop-yarn/
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown -R yarn:hadoop /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/hadoop-yarn/
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown -R yarn:hadoop /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/hadoop-yarn/
ExecStart=/bin/true
Slice=hadoop-yarn.slice
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryLimit=1G

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The behaviour is the same :

- directories are created
- systemctl daemon-reload
- devices/hadoop-yarn directory is deleted

I don't have any other ideas. Any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by systematically modifying each active service one by one to identify the root cause. I disabled each service using the command `systemctl disable <service>` and then reloaded the daemon with `systemctl daemon-reload` until I pinpointed the problematic service.

Ultimately, I discovered that the culprit was the Prometheus exporter, which I had set up as a service using this repository: https://github.com/NVIDIA/dcgm-exporter. It was unexpected since its primary function is to collect metrics, but it was indeed causing the problem. Notably, starting, stopping, or restarting this service had no effect on the cgroups directory, so I decided to keep it disabled.